# React Js Setstate not update input value of object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, reactjs, object

**React Js Setstate not update input value of object array
Below the code please help ?**

It's update just state I would like to make a dynamic form edit.
I fetch data setstate properly but input values in object array not update.

```
class IncorporationForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {


        super(props);
        this.initialValue = this.props.value;


        this.state = {
            formtitle:'',
            outdate: '',
            person: '',
            returndate: '',
            username: '',
            shareholders: [{

                result: 'deneme', meetingnotes: '', email: '', companyname: '', purpose: '', contactname: '', id: '',
                files: [{

                    Fileorjname: '',
                    Filesysname: '',
                    Filetype: '',
                    Fileext: '',
                    Filepath: '',
                    Filesize:''

                }]

            }]


        };


    }

    componentWillReceiveProps = (nextProps) => {
        this.initialValue = nextProps.value;
        this.setState({ value: nextProps.value });
    };

    componentWillMount = () => {

        fetch(`/Form/MeetingFormDetailGetService?formidno=` + window.formid)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(function (data) {
                this.getData(data)
            }.bind(this))


        this._initDatePicker();
    }

    getData = (data) => {

        for (var i = 0; i < data.Shareholders.length - 1; i++) {

            this.setState({ shareholders: this.state.shareholders.concat([{ result: 'test mest', meetingnotes: '', email: '', companyname: '', purpose: '', contactname: '', id: '' }]) });

        }

        let idx = 1
        const newShareholders = this.state.shareholders.map((shareholder, sidx) => {
            if (idx !== sidx) return shareholder;
            return { ...shareholder, companyname: "hoop hoop" };
        });


        this.setState({

            outdate: moment(data.outdate).format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm"),
            formtitle: data.formtitle,
            person: data.person,
            returndate: moment(data.returndate).format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm"),
            shareholders: newShareholders

        })
        console.log("state")

        console.log(this.state)
            ;


    }

    _initDatePicker = () => {
        var $this = this;
        var gidis = this.refs.gidis;
        var donus = this.refs.donus;
        var currentDate = new Date();

        $(gidis).datetimepicker({
            locale: 'tr'
        }).on("dp.change", function (e) {

            this.handledate(e.currentTarget.value, "outdate" )

        }.bind(this));

        $(donus).datetimepicker({
            locale: 'tr'
        }).on("dp.change", function (e) {

            this.handledate(e.currentTarget.value, "returndate")

        }.bind(this));


    }

    handledate = (val,name) => {

        this.setState({ [name]: val });

    }

    handleUser = () => {

        fetch("User/GetUserName")
            .then(result => result.json())
            .then(items => this.setState({ items }))


    }


    _updateDate = (evt) => {
        console.log("new value ", this.refs.input.value);
    }
    _destroyDatePicker = (evt) =>{
        var element = this.refs.input;
        $(element).datetimepicker('destroy');
    }

    componentDidMount = (evt) => {


    }


    componentDidUpdate = (evt) => {



        this._initDatePicker();
    }
    componentWillUnmount = (evt) =>{
        this._destroyDatePicker();
    }

    handleNameChange = (evt) =>{

        const target = evt.target.getAttribute('name')
        const idno = evt.target.getAttribute('id')
        this.setState({ [target]: evt.target.value });  

        let idx = 1
        const newShareholders = this.state.shareholders.map((shareholder, sidx) => {
            if (idx !== sidx) return shareholder;
            return { ...shareholder, companyname: "hoop hoop" };
        });
        this.setState({ shareholders: newShareholders });
        update();

    }

    readFile = (evt) => {

        var data = new FormData();
        const idno = evt.target.getAttribute('id')
        console.log(idno)
        for (var i = 0; i < evt.target.files.length; i++) {
            data.append("files", evt.target.files[i])
        } 


        fetch("Form/UploadFile", {
            mode: 'no-cors',
            method: "POST",
            body: data
        }).then(function (res) {
            if (res.ok) {
                console.log("Perfect! ");
            } else if (res.status == 401) {
                console.log("Oops! ");
            }
        }, function (e) {
            alert("Error submitting form!");
            });


    }



    getUrlParameter = (name) => {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
    var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
    var results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    }



    handleShareholderNameChange = (idx) => (evt) => {
        let isimler = null;
        if (evt.target.files) {

            var data = new FormData();

            var fileresultdata;

            for (var i = 0; i < evt.target.files.length; i++) {
                data.append("files", evt.target.files[i])
            }



            fetch("Form/UploadFile", {
                mode: 'no-cors',
                method: "POST",
                body: data
            }).then((resp) => {
               return resp.json()
                // return myData;
                }).then((data) => {

                    var isimler = [];

                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        isimler.push({

                            Fileorjname: data[i].Fileorjname,
                            Filesystemname: data[i].Filesystemname,
                            Filetype: data[i].Filetype,
                            Fileext: data[i].Fileext,
                            Filepath: data[i].Filepath,
                            Filesize: data[i].Filesize



                        });
                    } 

                    const idno = 5;

                    console.log(data)
                    const newShareholders = this.state.shareholders.map((shareholder, sidx) => {
                        if (idx !== sidx) return shareholder;

                        return {
                            ...shareholder, files: isimler, id: idno
                        };
                    });

                    this.setState({ shareholders: newShareholders });




                })
                .catch(function (error) {

                    console.log(error);

                });  






        } else {
            const target = evt.target.getAttribute('name')
            const idno = evt.target.getAttribute('id')
            const newShareholders = this.state.shareholders.map((shareholder, sidx) => {
                if (idx !== sidx) return shareholder;

                return {
                    ...shareholder, [target]: evt.target.value, id: idno
                };
            });

            this.setState({ shareholders: newShareholders });
        }

        console.log(this.state)

    }



    handleSubmit = (evt) => {

        evt.preventDefault();



        this.setState({ username: window.myVal }); 



        setTimeout(function () {

            fetch('Form/MeetingFormHandle', {
                method: 'POST',
                mode: 'CORS',
                body: JSON.stringify(this.state),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'pragma': 'no-cache',
                    'cache-control': 'no-cache'
                }
            }).then(res => {
                return res;
            }).catch(err => err);


        }.bind(this), 300);


    }

    handleAddShareholder = (evt) => {
        evt.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ shareholders: this.state.shareholders.concat([{ result: '', meetingnotes: '', email: '', companyname: '', purpose: '', contactname: '', id: '' }]) });
    }

    handleRemoveShareholder = (idx) => () => {
        this.setState({ shareholders: this.state.shareholders.filter((s, sidx) => idx !== sidx) });
    }



    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <h2 className="form-big-title">Seyahat / Toplantı Formu</h2>
                <div className="row round-box-form">
                    <div className="col-md-3">
                        <h3 className="form-label-1">Form Başlığı</h3>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" value={this.state.formtitle}  name="formtitle" onChange={this.handleNameChange.bind(this)} />

                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-3">
                        <h3 className="form-label-1">Kişiler</h3>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="person" value={this.state.person} onChange={this.handleNameChange.bind(this)} />

                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-3">
                        <h3 className="form-label-1">Giriş Tarihi ve Saati</h3>
                        <input ref="gidis" type="text" id="gidis-date" name="outdate" value={this.state.outdate} className="form-control" onClick={this.handleNameChange.bind(this)}/>
                </div>
                    <div className="col-md-3">
                        <h3 className="form-label-1">Çıkış Tarihi ve Saati</h3>
                        <input ref="donus" type="text" className="form-control" name="returndate" value={this.state.returndate} onClick={this.handleNameChange.bind(this)}/>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <h2 className="form-mid-title">Görüşme Detayları</h2>

                {this.state.shareholders.map((shareholder, idx) => (

                    <div className="shareholder">

                        <div className="row round-box-form">
                            <div onClick={this.handleRemoveShareholder(idx)} className="form-item-close-cont"><img src="/content/images/close-form-02.png" /></div>
                            <div className="col-md-12">
                                <h3 className="form-label-1">Toplantı Amacı</h3>
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    name="purpose"
                                    id={`${idx + 1} `}
                                    defaultValue={ "test mest"}
                                    value={shareholder.purpose}
                                    onChange={this.handleShareholderNameChange(idx)}
                                    className="form-control" />
                            </div>
                            <br />
                            <div className="col-md-3">
                                <h3 className="form-label-1">Şirket Adı</h3>
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    name="companyname"
                                    id={`${idx + 1} `}
                                    value={this.companyname}
                                    onChange={this.handleShareholderNameChange(idx)}
                                    className="form-control" />
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-3">
                                <h3 className="form-label-1">Görüşülen Kişi</h3>
                                <input

                                    type="text"
                                    name="contactname"
                                    id={`${idx + 1} `}
                                    value={this.state.shareholders.contactname}
                                    onChange={this.handleShareholderNameChange(idx)}
                                    className="form-control" />

                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-3">
                                <h3 className="form-label-1">E-mail Adresi</h3>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control"
                                    name="email"
                                    id={`${idx + 1} `}
                                    value={this.state.shareholders.email}
                                    onChange={this.handleShareholderNameChange(idx)}
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-3">
                                <h3 className="form-label-1">Kartvizit Fotoğrafı & Dökümanlar</h3>
                                <input
                                    type="file"
                                    name="files"
                                    id={`${idx + 1} `}
                                    onChange={this.handleShareholderNameChange(idx)}
                                    className="form-control" multiple />
                            </div>

                            <div className="col-md-6">
                                <h3 className="form-label-1">Toplantı Notları</h3>
                                <textarea
                                    type="text"
                                    name="meetingnotes"
                                    id={`${idx + 1} `}
                                    value={this.state.shareholders.meetingnotes}
                                    onChange={this.handleShareholderNameChange(idx)}
                                    rows="4"
                                    className="form-control inputdata">
                                </textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-6">
                                <h3 className="form-label-1">Sonuç</h3>
                                <textarea className="form-control inputdata"
                                    name="result"
                                    id={`${idx + 1} `}
                                    value={this.state.shareholders.result}
                                    onChange={this.handleShareholderNameChange(idx)}
                                    rows="4" ></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <br />

                        </div>


                    </div>

                ))}

                <div className="row">
                    <a onClick={this.handleSubmit} className="save-btn" href="">Kaydet</a>

                    <a onClick={this.handleAddShareholder} className="add-btn" id="add-meeting" href="">Görüşme Ekle</a>
                </div>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<IncorporationForm />, document.getElementById('seyForm'));
```

Comment: Please try to limit the code to the parts relevant to your question. It would also be nice if you tidied up the formatting a bit, and clarified your question.

Comment: I think it's clear reactjs not update objects array of  input value in html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then re-write your question and you might get answers. You have lots of unnecessary code in there that has nothing to do with you question!